# Online FFT of simulated signal

Tags: matlab, fft, discrete-signals, signal-analysis

it is a couple of weeks that I am thinking about the following: I have a tool which is able to simulate the dynamic behavior a steel tower exhibites due to the coupled action of wind and waves. Currently, to damp the oscillations, I am controlling the acceleration of the tower top by means of a standard feedback loop.

By the way, this procedure is rather cumbersome and suboptimal: I damp the tower oscillation even when it's not needed, since the mentioned oscillation cannot jeopardize the system. Therefore, I am thinking of a triggering method: this trigger should be based on online FFT analysis of the tower oscillations: if the FFT amplitude is above a certain risk-threshold, the control loop must be activated.

Now the question is: I am used to post-process full time series by means of FFT, but in my case the FFT should be performed on the simulated signal while the simulation is running.
Do you know any way I could perform kind of step-by-step FFT analysis?

Comment: I guess you need the short-time Fourier transform: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform#Discrete-time_STFT

Comment: well, it appears that sliding fft may be the answer: thanks for the hint.